# 'Home Town' or 'Hometown'?

Tags: vocabulary

Macmillan has only the entry **[Home Town](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/home-town)**.

Oxford also has only the entry **[Home Town](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/home-town?q=home%20town)** (although all examples suggested have **hometown** written).

VERSUS

Cambridge has only the entry **[Hometown](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hometown)**.

Microsoft Word keeps correcting me (I use BrE dictionary). It underlines **Home town**: I should write **Hometown**.

1) Which is the word I should use: **Home Town** or **Hometown**?

I've read [here](http://thatotherpaper.com/style_guide/diction/home_town_vs_hometown.html) that:

***Home town*** is used for “My **home town** is Flower Mound.” Home is modifying the noun, town.

**Hometown** is an adjective, as in “My **hometown** memories.”

2) Is this all right? Do both words exist, one as a noun and the other as an adjective? If it is the case, why the dictionaries don't have both entries?

Answer (score 3):

**Hometown** as a noun is American English. **Home town** (n.) is British English.

Since it's a two-word phrase in British English, it would need to be converted into a [compound adjective](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp) by using a hyphen, rather than combining them into one word: "My **home-town** memories" rather than "**hometown** memories". In American English, "hometown" is also the adjective form.

That's probably why "hometown" isn't appearing in your BrE dictionary searches. "Home-town" may not either, since many compound nouns don't have dictionary entries.